# Match from the third word onwards in a string with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to return `dolor sit amet` from the following string -

```
$title = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet';
preg_match('/^(?:\w+\s+){2}(.)+/', $title, $matches);
```

It's only matching the last letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the repetition operator inside the group:

```
preg_match('/^(?:\w+\s+){2}(.+)/', $title, $matches);
```

Otherwise, the group just captures one character.

Comment: @user2924019 https://regex101.com/r/mZT4AJ/1 The regexp matches the whole string, the capture group captures `dolor sit amet`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^(?:\w+\s+){2}(.+)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/_acPNOyF5fiRfeab)

Putting the plus outside of the capture group: `(.)+`, as in your original code, is going to capture--potentially--*multiple instances* of ***individual characters***, when you want to capture is, instead, a *single instance* of multiple characters.

You're only capturing the final character, instead of the final three words, because it's capturing and then "throwing away" all of these characters...

```
dolor sit ame
```

one-by-one, before finally capturing and returning the last `t`.

Comment: Nice web app. Will use in the future!